# Move a div element at the center of the outer div

Tags: css, html

I have 3 buttons and a div element . I want all of them to be placed one below the other . I am able to center the buttons but unable to center the div .

The buttons are

a ) Facebook sharing button

b ) Twitter follow

c) Twiiter share

d ) Google+1 share

After haveing done all the hardwork of implementing these buttons it seems strange but yes i am stuck at simple display :(

Can someone help me to allign then logically one below the another .

Code :

```
<div id ="outer" class="text-center">
    <img id = "share_button" src = "images/share_button.png" >
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/IXXXXg" 
       class="twitter-follow-button" 
       data-show-count="false">Follow @IXXXg</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=&amp;url=https://twitter.com/IXXXXXg" 
       class="twitter-share-button" 
       data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="inner" class="g-plusone" 
         data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="thanks.php">  
        <button class="btn btn-danger " type="button">Skip </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried the following CSS but does not work :

```
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any work around to get the div placed correctly below the buttons ?
[image]

Comment: Can you post your style sheet, or at least, the style definitions for `.g-plusone` and `.text-center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you wanted? => http://jsbin.com/ajoqan/3/edit

However, it is better to use CSS margin property than to use line breaks. Line breaks belong in a text.

For reference
The HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="outer" class="text-center">
    <img id = "share_button" src = "images/share_button.png" >
    <a href="https://twitter.com/IXXXXg" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @IXXXg</a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=&amp;url=https://twitter.com/IXXXXXg" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
    <div id="inner" class="g-plusone" style="border:1px solid red;" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300">Google+</div>
    <a href="thanks.php">  
        <button class="btn btn-danger " type="button">Skip </button>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```css
#outer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer > * { /* all elements in div #outer  */
  margin: 10px 25%;
  width: 50%;
}
/* alternatively you can do

#outer > * {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width: 50%;` from your CSS and your problem would be solved.You css will like this

```
#inner 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope it works.